# Conda dependencies do not install on local package build

Tags: python, conda

I am building a Python package using `conda-build`. Right now, my structure looks like this:

```
- my_recipe/
    - meta.yaml
    - build.sh
```

And my `meta.yaml` reads thusly:

```
package:
  name: my_pkg
version: "0.2.0"

source:
  path: ../my_pkg

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools
  run:
    - python
    - pandas
    - numpy
    - plotly
    - matplotlib
    - pyqtgraph
    - pyopengl
    - gdal
    - scipy
    - scikit-image
```

The package itself builds correctly when I run

`conda-build my_recipe/`

and it installs successfully when I run

`conda install -n my_env --use-local ~/miniconda3/envs/my_env/conda-bld/linux-64/my_pkg-0.2.0-py36_0.tar.bz2`

However, none of the dependencies listed under `run` seem to install along with the package. For example, when I import the package in Python it says that `pandas` could not be found.

Are my dependencies listed in the correct location? Do I also need to list the dependencies in `setup.py`? The documentation is not very clear on where this information should be.

Comment: Rather that specifying the full path, the purpose of the `--use-local` is to go and look at the `conda-bld` folder. I suspect the cause is that you've listed the full path to the file rather than just the name of the package, since full paths to files don't install dependencies. Try with `conda install -n my_env --use-local my_pkg`

Comment: @darthbith I can confirm the behavior and I'm not pointing to the directory. Like OP, when referencing a built package (located in `conda-bld` and built using `conda-build`), `conda install` does not install `run` dependencies. Why am I trying to use conda again?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. Is there any known solution. The two solutions below doesnt work for me.

Comment: Could you please accept/upvote an answer? This question should be used as the canonical one for this issue, but lack of upvoting prevents this. I believe the community wiki one I added is the proper answer, but I can’t upvote myself.

Comment: My issue was that I was using the full filename, but you only need the *package name*

My zip file is named `ipypdf-0+untagged.105.g7f64c9d.dirty-py_0.tar.bz2`

So I `CD` into the directory it is stored in, then use this command to install it. 

`conda install --use-local ipypdf -c conda-forge`

`-c conda-forge` is included for the dependencies

Comment: When you specify a full path to a conda package on disk, conda will ignore all dependencies.  It's an ancient misfeature of conda that is similar to using `--no-deps`.  

i wish it would warn you what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @darthbith, using the `--use-local` flag with the package name,

```bash
conda install -n my_env --use-local my_pkg
```

works as intended. Using a path to a tarball directly triggers Conda to install without dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Specifying the channel works for me.

Actually, you don't even need to specify the full path. For instance, from the folder where the recipe is located (the meta.yaml and build.sh), I build my package with:

```
conda-build . --output-folder ./build
```

Then, I install the package with:

```
conda install my_package_name -c ./build
```

This will also install the dependencies specified in the meta.yaml. Here is how my meta.yaml looks like.

```
package:
  name: my_package_name
  version: 0.0.1

source:
  path: .

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools

  run:
    - python
    - numpy
    - holopy
    - scikit-image
```

Comment: Did you try just `--use-local pkg_name`?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me while `--use-local` did not!

Answer (score 1):

I've had luck telling `conda` to treat the local directory as a channel:

```
conda install my-package-name -c file:///FULL_PATH_TO_CONDA/envs/my_env/conda-bld/
```

I figured this out based on instructions [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html), although note I didn't have to run `conda index` first because `conda build` had already created `repodata.json` files.

Comment: The `--use-local` flag should also work just fine in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the `--update-deps` flag when installing a local package does install the package's dependencies, as expected. Like this:

```
conda install --use-local --update-deps my-package-name
```

Comment: The `--use-local` is sufficient.