# conda install in test environment

Tags: conda, environment, conda-build

I try to create my own (first) `conda` package, spent the recent evenings tabbing between google, stack-overflow and my terminal. I am stuck on the following:

I can successfully build from my project (named `mcm`) directory with `conda build .`. After that, I find as expected the tarball in `<my-dev-env>/conda-bld/noarch/mcm-v1.0a4-py_0.tar.bz2`.

Now I would find it natural to test the package in a fresh environment:

```
conda create -n test
conda activate test
conda install --use-local mcm
```

But the package is not found - maybe logical, because `test` doesn't know about my other environment. I also tried from my dev-environment with equal outcome

```
conda install -n test --use-local mcm
```

The error is always as follows:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - mcm

... [list of channels follows]
```

Of course, I can install with path to the actual tarball file, but then it excludes dependencies, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49823033/conda-dependencies-do-not-install-on-local-package-build).

**My actual question is how to make this work**, but also to (dis-)confirm my nagging feeling that I'm doing it all wrong. I also have been reading a lot on the `conda-build` docu pages, in particular [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html).

Or is building `conda` packages for own projects (not intending to publish beyond working colleagues) overkill, as building `pip` packages with `setuptools` seems so much easier? I just got influenced by the statement that installing with `pip` might break the `conda` dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7024. This ticket is marked as closed, but I still seem to have that issue with `conda 4.8.3`.

Well, the work-arounds presented there work for me, e.g.

```
$ conda install -c file:///home/.../miniconda3/envs/dev-env/conda-bld/ mcm
```

This is at least a first step.

Now, to share with dear colleagues, I found this one:
[How can I host my own private conda repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359147/how-can-i-host-my-own-private-conda-repository). Ideally this would be located on a file server, but at work we are now infested with OneDrive. Maybe that will do as well.