# conda does not install dependencies from meta.yaml when creating a custom package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I've a pip package and want to create a conda package of that same pacakge as well. Most of the packages are not available on official anaconda so gonna create from conda-forge

The build goes successful by this command

```
conda build . -c conda-forge
```

meta.yaml file

```
{% set name = "mypackage" %}
{% set version = "2.0" %}
{% set build_number = "3" %}

package:
  name: "{{ name|lower }}"
  version: "{{ version }}"
  
source:
  path: ./mypackage_source_code

build:
  noarch: generic
  number: "{{ build_number }}"
  string: "{{ version }}"

requirements:
  run:
    - python
    - 'pandas>=1.3.2'
    - 'sqlalchemy>=1.4.19'
    - 'snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.3.1'
    - 'cryptography==3.3.2'
    - 'snowflake-connector-python==2.6.2'
    - 'numpy>=1.18.1'
    - 'dash==1.21.0'
    - 'dash-core-components==1.17.1'
    - 'dash-html-components==1.1.4'
    - 'dash-bootstrap-components==0.13.0'
    - 'dash-table==4.12.0'
    - 'pyarrow==5.0.0'
    - 'pyyaml>=5.4.1'
    - 'certifi==2020.12.5'
    - 'pyodbc==4.0.31'
    - 'jupyter==1.0.0'
    - 'jupyter-dash==0.4.0'

# test:
 #   imports:
 #     - mdodata

about:
  home: https://mypackage.com
  summary: This is the python version of the my-package library
  license: Proprietary
```

This is what my conda build generates

```
mypackage-2.0-2.0.tar.tz2/
├── info/
│   ├── recipe
|   ├── about.json
|   ├── files
|   ├── git
|   ├── hash_input.json
|   ├── index.json
|   ├── paths.json
├── site-packages/
│   ├── mypackage
|   ├── mypackage-2021.10-py3.6.egg-info
```

The index file contain all the dependencies in depends tag that I mentioned in meta.yaml file and the index file is given below

```
{
  "arch": null,
  "build": "2.0",
  "build_number": 3,
  "depends": [
    "certifi 2020.12.5",
    "cryptography 3.3.2",
    "dash 1.21.0",
    "dash-bootstrap-components 0.13.0",
    "dash-core-components 1.17.1",
    "dash-html-components 1.1.4",
    "dash-table 4.12.0",
    "jupyter 1.0.0",
    "jupyter-dash 0.4.0",
    "numpy >=1.18.1",
    "pandas >=1.3.2",
    "pyarrow 5.0.0",
    "pyodbc 4.0.31",
    "python",
    "pyyaml >=5.4.1",
    "snowflake-connector-python 2.6.2",
    "snowflake-sqlalchemy 1.3.1",
    "sqlalchemy >=1.4.19"
  ],
  "license": "Proprietary",
  "name": "mypackage",
  "noarch": "generic",
  "platform": null,
  "subdir": "noarch",
  "timestamp": 1637563872943,
  "version": "2.0"
}
```

When I install the package, it only install or copy the source code. It do not install all the dependencies that I mentioned it meta.yaml file under requirements. For example when I import the package in python it says that `pandas` could not be found

I install the package through the command that is given below.

```
conda install --use-local mypackage-2.0-2.0.tar.tz2
```

Please let me know if I am doing any thing wrong or How we can install local package wit all its dependencies through conda.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I can't mark it because no one has ever upvoted an answer (after 3 years!). https://stackoverflow.com/q/49823033/570918  Namely, specify just the package name with the `--use-local` flag, not the tarball. If you specify the tarball, Conda assumes a force-install mode. Specifically, the proper answer is from a comment, but is provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69586997/570918

Comment: Thank  you. by replacing the tarball with package name I can successfully install package with all dependencies.

Comment: Would you mind upvoting any answers on the duplicate so that we can close vote this one?